# How to disable Mojave's floating thumbnail screenshot preview?

Tags: screen-capture, mojave

How do I disable this:

[image]

after taking screenshot?

Comment: More importantly, could you keep the thumbnail but not have to wait 5 seconds for the file to be saved, AND when you take two consecutive screenshots it doesn't show the thumbnail of the first one?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> to bring up the Screenshot menu
2. Uncheck Options > Show Floating Thumbnail

This will prevent it from showing up.

This will also disable the ~5 second saving delay (screenshots will be saved immediately).

Comment: Have you noticed it still takes 5 seconds to show the file on the desktop, even if you disable this? I could go off on one of my 'fun rants' about this 'improvement'... but I shan't ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin Screw it. I'm gonna look into copying the frameworks over from high Sierra to completely disable this feature.

Comment: I have great difficulty trying to see the logic behind this new 'feature' at all. Gimme mi screenshot & gimme it nao !! ;-)

Comment: @JBis If that's successful, please leave as another answer, I'd like to see!

Comment: @Tetsujin Hmm. I just checked again and it seems to be saving immediately. Can you check yours again just to confirm?

Comment: Hmmm.. odd. I toggled it again & the delay is gone. I'm currently on 10.14.1 beta, so either something changed, or I'm going slightly mad in my old age ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin [I went off on such a "fun rant"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/432466/), before discovering that my question was a duplicate. I don't even mind the down-votes. It felt good to point out everything that's wrong with this feature. :-D

Comment: @Mentalist Yeah - I do like the 'new' cmd/shift/5 for many reasons, but this bit had to go bye-bye for me too.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yeah, I forgot that we no longer resort to Terminal hacks to make screenshots work as we want. Old habits die hard. I think I had actually found the option to disable the Floating Thumbnail long ago. But after a clean OS installation, moving up a few versions of macOS, I couldn't recall the details.