# Quickly save Screenshot in MacOS Mojave with keyboard Shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, mojave, screen-capture

In MacOS Mojave, when I take a screenshot with `CMD + SHIFT + 4` (so this isn't a normal screen shot, it's a screenshot of a little part of my screen), it takes several seconds before it's saved. Actually, the OS allows me to click on my screenshot and edit it for instance.

But what if I want it to be immediatly saved after I took the screenshot with a shortcut Keyboard ? (This feature changed in MacOS Mojave, before this version of MacOS, the screenshot was indeed imemediatly saved).

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338066/how-to-disable-mojaves-floating-thumbnail-screenshot-preview) explains how to permanently remove the waiting, but what if I want to remove it on particular moment and not always ?

Comment: Check this out https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361

Comment: @Buscar웃 I edited my question because it was duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Didn't realise that keyboard shortcut was asked. Jump right to the last para.</sup>

You can look at the screenshot in the bottom right corner of the screen. If you think that the SS was taken fine, you can swipe right on it with two fingers(like in Safari) and it will be saved at that moment.

You can edit it(or maybe not) by clicking on it and then done and share etc will be there.

You can also drag and drop it if supported by places you want to use the SS at so immediately.

The question you linked didn't mention "remember selection" in options of <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>. So if you uncheck it and the said shortcut, instant saving!