# How to increase delay time for Floating Thumbnail of screenshot?

Tags: macos, catalina, screen-capture

After several hours search to finding the solution I just find [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/338066/301671), but my goal is exactly the opposite of removing floating thumbnail. Its delay time is 5 seconds but I wanna increase it to 1 minute.

[image]

How I can increase the floating thumbnail delay time after each screenshot?

Comment: I searched for a way to do this and don't believe it's possible as of now.

Comment: @coffee-grinder, It was hard-coded, and it is not possible for users to change it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. In any case, there seems to be nothing useful here to answer the question `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture.plist`

Comment: @DarwinOSX, Even `defaults write com.apple.screencapture autohide-delay -float 60` doesn't help me.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a relatively close solution: Open Automator.app, choose New, and pick Folder Action. You'll see at the top it says "Folder Action receives files and folders added to:" and a file pop-up. Use the pop-up to select your Screenshots destination folder (mine's in my Documents folder, I think by default). Then on the left column pick the Files & Folders Library, and from its list drag "Open Finder Items" into the big empty space. It will say "Open with:" and another pop-up, this time a pop-up of your applications. Choose Preview, for a fairly universal tool for images. I've attached a screenshot :) of the relevant part of the Automator window. Now save the Folder Action with a recognizable name. Take a screenshot, and a few moments after the screenshot's little preview disappears, it will open in Preview.
[image: Here's a screenshot :) of my automator as described]

Automator will let you add all sorts of additional actions - go wild!

HTH

Comment: This is the way +1 and well done

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to alter the timing of this feature on macOS Ventura. You would need to access the image from elsewhere (the location where you save it is configurable) if you can't snag it in time. (Use [Folder Actions or Automator or AppleScript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/458840/5472) for this)

You also might find a third party app to assist in holding the image for longer times, but I can't think of a viable one these days now that [Skitch is isn't something I use regularly](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/skitch-snap-mark-up-share/id425955336?mt=12).